# Unable to get view server version from device emulator-5554

Tags: android

I was supposed to be using hierarchy view but my hierarchy view shows an empty screen, I saw the solution for it on stack overflow  to be resetting the adb but when I try that I get this

```
error on Console in Android Device Monitor


[2016-01-01 12:19:07 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device emulator-5554
[2016-01-01 12:21:24 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

[2016-01-01 12:21:25 - hierarchyviewer]Failed to remove forward for device emulator-5554: Connection refused: connect
[2016-01-01 12:21:25 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
```

Comment: Did you fix it? Thanks.

Comment: nopes I was not able to solve it .I tried with genymotion emulator also but I wasnt able to solve it